# How to get access to my localhost DB if I change host to 0.0.0.0?

Tags: mysql, macos, root

I was trying to get access to my DB from my second machine via Wi-Fi. I thought if I change root@localhost to root@0.0.0.0 it will allow me to connect to db. But I was wrong. Now I can't connect to my DB neither from localhost and second machine.

How to switch root@0.0.0.0 to root@localhost? I know the root password.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: see [How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) .. Stop and start the MySQL server with `--skip-grant-tables` then you should also be able to reconfigure the root account host again and or add `root@localhost` again

Comment: it this way the data will be safe?

Comment: not if the MySQL server is directly accessible from SQL clients from the outside (over the internet)..

Comment: It's not dublicate because the problem not in passwords. The problem in 0.0.0.0 or localhost. How to change it?

Comment: Geuss you didn't understand it? boot MySQL with  `--skip-grant-tables` then you can update in the `mysql.user` table that account `root@0.0.0.0` to `root@localhost`  with a simple update query and then start the server without using `--skip-grant-tables`

Comment: Thanks! I did it